# How to change color of Materialize multiple select checkbox?

Tags: css, colors, css-selectors, html-select, materialize

How can I change the teal color of the Materialize multiple select checkboxes?

[image]

I'm able to change the color of the options:

[image]

```css
ul.dropdown-content.select-dropdown li span {
    color: #E63594; 
}
```

And the color of the headings/selections:

[image]

```css
.select-dropdown {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the checkmarks, use:

```
[type="checkbox"]:checked+span:not(.lever):before {

    border-right: 2px solid firebrick !important;
    border-bottom: 2px solid firebrick !important;

}
```

```js
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems,{
    isMultiple:true});
  });
```

```css
[type="checkbox"]:checked+span:not(.lever):before {

    border-right: 2px solid firebrick !important;
    border-bottom: 2px solid firebrick !important;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


 <div class="input-field col s12">
    <select multiple>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <label>Materialize Multiple Select</label>
  </div>
```